# Fail over to DNS provider

Tags: domain-name-system

****Dns Server that is stand alone backup to dns service with DNS provider.****

We recently had our primary dns service provider go off line and our clients could not get to our web servers. It is possible to create an Windows Server 2008 DNS server and have it setting here off line and outside of our local domain and LAN to act as fail over?

In the event that this same situations happens , in theory, Could I plug it in and tell our registrar the new IP address? I realize that there would be no real time sync on the local external dns server here.

Would that work?

Thanks

Comment: How many domains do you need to handle?  I don't recommend doing this yourself unless you need fine grain control of dozens of zones.  There are many DNS Service providers that provide near 100% uptime.  If you need failover, then consider using a provider that can serve as a secondary DNS rather trying to do this internally.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* have at least 2 online DNS servers for anything production. A single server is just asking for trouble.

You can list 4 servers on most domains and many larger DNS providers have even more than that. You want at *least* two. If you can't self-host more than one, find a provider and use a slave zone.